# Missing table border bottom

Tags: html, css, jsreport

This is my problem:
I'm create a report at JSReport and I'm use #each from handlebars to generate data in my table, but, when break page the border-bottom is missing, showing only at the end of the table.

Follow images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lLeg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEqGG.png)

I need that in both situations they show the lower border at the end, as in this situation below which indicates that the table is finished.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGRQe.png)

Follow the HTML and CSS of the table.

```
HTML
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1 class="font-weight-bold mt-3">DADOS DO PRODUTO/SERVIÇO</h1>
<table class="contentInfo contentInfosGerais tabelaProdutos" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">CÓD. PRODUTO</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">DESCRIÇÃO DO PRODUTO/SERVIÇO</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">NCM/SH</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">CST</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">CFOP</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">UNID.</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">QUANTIDADE</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">VALOR UNITÁRIO</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">VALOR TOTAL</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">BC ICMS</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">VALOR ICMS</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">VALOR IPI</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">ALIQ. ICMS</th>
            <th scope="col cabecalhoTabela">ALIQ. IPI</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each (populaTabelaProdutos NewDataSet.nfeProc.[0].NFe.[0].infNFe.[0].det)}}
            <tr class="table-content text-justify">
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{codProd}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{xProd}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{ncm}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{cst}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{cfop}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{uCom}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{valor qCom}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{valor vUnCom}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{valor vProd}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{bcIcms}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{vlrIcms}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{vlrIpi}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{aliqIcms}}
                </td>
                <td class="produtos table-content-infos">
                    {{valor aliqIpi}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>

CSS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.contentInfo {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.contentInfo td,
.contentInfo th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 40px;
}
body .tabelaProdutos {
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
}

body .tabelaProdutos thead th {
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px !important;
    line-height: 20px;
}

body .tabelaProdutos tbody td {
    border: none !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #000 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #000 !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

/* This style i'm use to break page and agroup the content togheter */
tr {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

I need the border-bottom to appear solely at the end of the table and not dividing each line

Thanks for help!

Comment: As posted I took your table and made multiple TR from that - it shows, using your CSS the bottom border.  I created an answer just to test this but deleted it due to that

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule which adds a bottom border to the cells in the last row:

```
body .tabelaProdutos tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps target the class on the tr `<tr class="table-content text-justify"` and/or  `td`  `class="produtos table-content-infos"` but not really an issue with your answer in the context of the OP question.

Comment: This doesn't work because it's a single table but it's divided into three pages and only at the end of table show's the border-bottom